# GXT 3, editable grid, need to perform action on enter

Tags: gwt, datagrid, extjs, gxt

I am new to GXT 3, and am confused by the API. Perhaps you could clarify.

In Editor Grid, how do I catch and examine keyboard keys pressed inside a cell in focus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create your grid and pass it to GridEditing instance:

   ```
    final GridEditing<MyType> ge = new GridInlineEditing<MyType>(grid);
   ```

   // note: final Grid grid = new Grid(store, cm);

   // note: ColumnModel cm = new ColumnModel(configs);

   // note: List> configs = new ArrayList>();
2. Construct your ColumnConfig

   ```
   ColumnConfig<MyType, String> kanji = new ColumnConfig<MyType, String>(kfgProps.kanji());
   ```

   // note: kfgProps here extends PropertyAccess
3. Add your editor

   ```
   ge.addEditor(kanji, text);
   ```

   // note: text = new TextField();
4. Add your DomHandler

   ```
   text.addDomHandler(new KeyDownHandler() {

       @Override public void onKeyDown(KeyDownEvent event) {

           if (KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER == event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode()) {

               // do whatever

           }
       }

   }, KeyDownEvent.getType());
   ```

Comment: Thanks! One more question: if the **if** statement includes other conditions beside testing what key was pressed, and that condition is not met, i.e. the **if** evaluates to _false_, how do I proceed with the otherwise regular pressed key action. For example, I press TAB. The **if** condition is if TAB and something else. Something else is false. I want my having pressed TAB, to proceed moving focus to the next cell in the grid.